# Is it possible to make ons-list as horizontal?

Tags: onsen-ui

Most ons-list provided by OnsenUI are normally vertical. I wonder if it is possible to make it into horizontal. Something like a possibility to scroll from left to right.

Comment: The result should look like: http://jsfiddle.net/V5zWT/12/

Comment: Check the `ons-carousel` component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the solution as follows:

HTML:

```
<ons-list class="wrapper-album">
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" class="internal" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="onItemClick(item);">
        <img ng-src="{{item.thumb}}"></img>
    </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper-album {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.internal {
    display: inline;
}
```